# document.getElementsByTagName() will dynamically change

Tags: javascript, dom

I use `document.getElementsByTagName` to get all the images in the page and store the array in a variable called `imgs`. Then every time I use `document.createElement` and `document.appendChild` to create a new image tag and append it to the document, the content of the variable `imgs` would dynamically change, which means it will include the newly-added image tag. According to my understanding, I already saved the content in the variable `imgs` before, so it should keep constant all the way. For example. if I save the length of `imgs` in another variable called `imgsLength`, it doesn't change even if I add another img tag dynamically to the document. So I'm a little bit confused about this inconsistency between `imgs` and `imgsLength`.

Comment: Whenever you save length of some array (nodeList or other type of collection), actually you only copy returned value from length property and value types as known are immutable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misunderstanding objects.

`getElementsByTagName()` returns a NodeList object, containing a live view of the matching elements.
This object is *mutable*; it will change in response to DOM mutations.

`var img = getElementsByTagName()` creates a variable that references this same object.  It doesn't copy anything.

`imgs.length` returns an immutable number representing the current length of the NodeList.

`var imgLength = imgs.length` creates a variable that references this immutable number.
When the NodeList changes, `imgs.length` will refer to a different number; that does not affect the variable that refers to its previous value.